# What's the proper way to link against an executable on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, ld, mingw-w64

I need to use some symbols from the main executable in a plugin.

Linking against the executable causes the following linker errors:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ example.cpp -shared -I.. -std=c++11 -o test.dll ../../test.exe -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -fvisibility=hidden
[..]/test.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x500): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
[..]/test.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x560): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x60): first defined here
[..]/test.exe: In function `ZlsRSoRK5Color':
[..]src/tools.h:212: multiple definition of `operator<<(std::ostream&, Color const&)'
/tmp/ccC97Hkz.o:example.cpp:(.text$_ZlsRSoRK5Color[__ZlsRSoRK5Color]+0x0): first defined here
../../test.exe: In function `ZN7MessageILb0EElsIcEERS0_OT_':
[..]/src/tools.h:241: multiple definition of `Message<false>& Message<false>::operator<< <char>(char&&)'
/tmp/ccC97Hkz.o:example.cpp:(.text$_ZN7MessageILb0EElsIcEERS0_OT_[__ZN7MessageILb0EElsIcEERS0_OT_]+0x0): first defined here
[..]/test.exe:crtexe.c:(.idata+0x3f0): multiple definition of `_imp__GeoIP_country_code'
[..]/test.exe:crtexe.c:(.idata+0x3f0): first defined here
[..]/test.exe:crtexe.c:(.idata+0x3f4): multiple definition of `_imp__GeoIP_country_name'
[..]/test.exe:crtexe.c:(.idata+0x3f4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now if I build the main executable with `-shared -Wl,--export-all-symbols` then linking against `test.exe` works,
but the Windows loader (or at least the wine one) complains about `test.exe` being a dll.

So I need to re-link `test.exe` once again without `-shared` so I am able to run `test.exe`.

i.e.:

```
# produce the import executable
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ tools.o main.o [...] -o ../test.exe -shared -Wl,--export-all-symbols [...] -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

# produce the real executable
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ tools.o main.o [...] -o ../test.exe -Wl,--export-all-symbols [...] -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

That's super hackish, but at the end I do have a working plugin...

To come to my question:

**Is there a better way to achive this (without passing around function pointers)?**

I know `MSVC` is able to output import libraries for executables, is there a similar way for `MinGW`?

I have tried to add `-Wl,--out-implib,test.a` to the linker flags to get an import library for the executable,
but `--out-implib` seems to be ignored when linking an executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where you probably *do* want to qualify the callback symbols, in the `.exe`, with the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute. Cross-compiling on my Linux Mint Debian box, the following minimal example works for me:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int __declspec(dllexport) foo( int bar ){ return bar << 2; }
int main(){ printf( "%d\n", foo( 4 ) ); return 0; }

$ mingw32-gcc -o ~/src/exp/foo.exe -Wl,--out-implib=libfoo.dll.a foo.c
```

This produces **both** a **working** executable, **and** an import library to map its exported symbols, for use when linking plug-ins, with just **one** invocation of the linker in the preceding commands, (as seen when running the executable under wine, and listing the import library using the native linux `nm` tool):

```
$ ~/src/exp/foo.exe
16

$ nm -A libfoo.dll.a
libfoo.dll.a:d000002.o:00000000 I _foo_exe_iname
libfoo.dll.a:d000002.o:00000000 i .idata$4
libfoo.dll.a:d000002.o:00000000 i .idata$5
libfoo.dll.a:d000002.o:00000000 i .idata$7
libfoo.dll.a:d000000.o:         U _foo_exe_iname
libfoo.dll.a:d000000.o:00000000 I __head_foo_exe
libfoo.dll.a:d000000.o:00000000 i .idata$2
libfoo.dll.a:d000000.o:00000000 i .idata$4
libfoo.dll.a:d000000.o:00000000 i .idata$5
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000001 a @feat.00
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000000 T _foo
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:         U __head_foo_exe
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000000 i .idata$4
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000000 i .idata$5
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000000 i .idata$6
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000000 i .idata$7
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000000 I __imp__foo
libfoo.dll.a:d000001.o:00000000 t .text
```

Likewise, the executable runs just fine in WinXP, (running within VirtualBox on the LMDE box, with ~/src/exp mapped as drive E: in the WinXP VM, and invoked from the MSYS shell):

```
$ /e/foo.exe
16
```

FWIW, I can reproduce your failure to create a runnable executable, when adding the `-shared` attribute to the linker invocation; as you note, that is intended for creating DLLs, (which differ from executables in format **only** in having a different magic number embedded in the header; otherwise they are fundamentally the same).

In summary:

- Don't specify `-shared` when linking the executable.
- Do qualify symbols to be exported from the executable with the
  `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute.
- Do specify the `-Wl,--out-implib=lib<exename>.dll.a` attribute, when
  linking the executable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good to know that the linker only emits an import library for explicitly exported symbols when linking an executable.
However, I would really like to avoid pollute a lot of symbols with `__declspec(dllexport)` / `API defines` just because of Windows.
But this is indeed a better solution than mine. Maybe the GNU people should consider adding an option to emit an import library for executables
without explicitly specifying `__declspec(dllexport)` - shouldn't be a lot of work for them since the code is already there for dlls.

Comment: @Thomas: I agree that a surfeit of `__declspec(dllexport)` attributes is just plain ugly. OTOH, you _really do not_ want to export all symbols from an executable, so I think that current GNU `ld` behaviour is correct. More elegant, perhaps, would be to declare a macro, `#define EXE_CALLBACK __declspec(dllexport)` say, and use that to qualify your exports; has the advantage that it emphasizes the particular significance of these symbols in your code. (Perhaps even consider defining it _conditionally_, as `__declspec(dllexport)` in the executable, and `__declspec(dllimport)` in your plug-ins).

Comment: @Thomas: FWIW, `mingw32-gcc -o foo.exe -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--out-implib=libfoo.dll.a foo.c` works just fine for me. It __does__ create the import library `libfoo.dll.a`; the problem I see with it is that this import library includes symbols which, IMO, do not belong there.

Comment: You are right, the linker indeed outputs an import library. I must have forgotten `-Wl,--export-all-symbols` when I have tested it. Quite embarrassing. Anyway, I found a solution to avoid `__declspec(dllexport)`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Like *Keith Marshall* stated in the comments, `-Wl,--out-implib` indeed works in combination with either:

- `-Wl,--export-all-symbols`
- by declaring symbols with `__declspec(dllexport)`
- or by providing a .def file

I went with the third option and wrote a bash script to generate a def file / version scripts on-the-fly to avoid exporting a lot of unneeded symbols.

The script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/tpoechtrager/1a645ac9f498c589a2bf).

Use it like:

```
export SYMBOLS_TO_EXPORT="*tools* *network* _Z8compressPvRjPKvjib ..." # use mangled names and skip leading underscores on i686
export HOSTPREFIX=i686-w64-mingw32 # unneeded on Windows
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ $(OBJS) `./gen_export_file $(OBJS)` -Wl,--out-implib=foo.exe.a -o foo.exe
```

Comment: Yes, creating a `.def` file, rather than using `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute qualification, would also work. It wouldn't be *my* preferred choice, however, because it a) adds a maintenance burden for the extra `.def` file, and b) it sacrifices the self-documentary advantage of having a *well chosen* macro name, expanding to `__declspec(dllexport)` to *clearly* identify your call-backs, right where they are defined in your source code.

Comment: @KeithMarshall: Right, your solution is indeed preferable.