# Reverse Dynamic Linking function call

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, windows

Consider the micro-kernel software architecture for an application.
I have a kernel and a component.

The component is a DLL that is loaded by the kernel during runtime using `LoadLibrary` API in Windows; and of course, exported functions can be called using `GetProcAddress`.

Now the component needs to send messages to the kernel. In other words the component which is a loaded DLL now, needs to call functions from the kernel. What is the right mechanism?

Comment: When you say "kernel" what do you mean by that? There are multiple uses of the word "kernel" in computer programming, and it's not clear exactly which one of the meanings is relevant here. You should also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Does it change the answer? Consider the micro-kernel architecture. The kernel forms the heart of the application.

Comment: So you are writing your own *operating system* kernel? Not e.g. a CUDA kernel? Please update your tags to reflect that, or at least spell it out in the question body.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do you think it is possible to call Windows APIs when one is writing its own operating system? The question is quiet clear.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg let alone that it is not possible to call such functions inside CUDA kernels, the context and question perfectly indicates the meaning of the kernel. Frankly speaking you're trying to leave comments to increase reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475042/1274747

For the MSVC, you would basically use the `__declspec(dllexport)` in the .exe. The compiler/linker generates the import library for the .exe, which then can be linked with the DLL, the DLL will then use the symbols from .exe.

Another option is to solve this by the "dependency inversion" - the .exe will not export the symbols, but will provide a (pure virtual) interface, which will be implemented inside the .exe and passed (via reference or pointer to the interface) into the DLL after loading. The DLL can then call methods on the interface, provided inside of the .exe. But indeed, as you speak of a microkernel, it depends if the virtual call overhead will be acceptable for you (although when exporting a function from the .exe, the method is AFAIK called via function pointer as well, so I wouldn't expect any significant difference).

**EDIT**

I just created an example, which is working for me (just a quick code, not much polishing, normally headers would be used etc.):

File "mydll.cpp":

```
// resolved against the executable
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
int __stdcall getSum(int a, int b);


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall callSum(int a, int b)
{
    return getSum(a, b);
}
```

File "myexe.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>

// export from the .exe
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall getSum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}


typedef int(__stdcall * callSumFn)(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    HMODULE hLibrary = LoadLibrary(TEXT("MyDll.dll"));
    if (!hLibrary)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to load library" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    callSumFn callSum = (callSumFn)GetProcAddress(hLibrary, "_callSum@8");
    if (!callSum)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to get function address" << endl;
        FreeLibrary(hLibrary);
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "callSum(3, 4) = " << callSum(3, 4) << endl;

    FreeLibrary(hLibrary);
    return 0;
}
```

The DLL is linked against "MyExe.lib", which is created when building the EXE. The `main()` calls the `callSum()` function from the DLL, which in turn calls the `getSum()` provided by the EXE.

That being said, I'd still prefer to use the "dependency inversion" and passing an interface to the DLL - for me it seems more clean and also more flexible (e.g. versioning by interface inheritance, etc.).

**EDIT #2**

As for the dependency inversion technique, it can be for example something like this:

File ikernel.hpp (provided by the kernel executable, not by the DLL):

```
#ifndef IKERNEL_HPP
#define IKERNEL_HPP

class IKernel
{
protected:
    // or public virtual, but then there are differences between different compilers
    ~IKernel() {}
public:
    virtual int someKernelFunc() = 0;
    virtual int someOtherKernelFunc(int x) = 0;
};

#endif
```

File "mydll.cpp":

```
#include "ikernel.hpp"

// if passed the class by pointer, can be extern "C", i.e. loadable by LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall callOperation(IKernel *kernel, int x)
{
    return kernel->someKernelFunc() + kernel->someOtherKernelFunc(x);
}
```

File "myexe.cpp":

```
#include "ikernel.hpp"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>

// the actual kernel definition
class KernelImpl: public IKernel
{
public:
    virtual ~KernelImpl() {}
    virtual int someKernelFunc()
    {
        return 10;
    }
    virtual int someOtherKernelFunc(int x)
    {
        return x + 20;
    }
};

typedef int(__stdcall * callOperationFn)(IKernel *kernel, int x);

int main()
{
    HMODULE hLibrary = LoadLibrary(TEXT("ReverseDll.dll"));
    if (!hLibrary)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to load library" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    callOperationFn callOperation = (callOperationFn)GetProcAddress(hLibrary, "_callOperation@8");
    if (!callOperation)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to get function address" << endl;
        FreeLibrary(hLibrary);
        return 1;
    }

    KernelImpl kernel;

    cout << "callOperation(kernel, 5) = " << callOperation(&kernel, 5) << endl;

    FreeLibrary(hLibrary);
    return 0;
}
```

As said this is more flexible and IMHO easier maintainable; the kernel can provide different callbacks for different DLL calls. If necessary, the DLL might as well provide implementation of some interface as specifier by the kernel, which will be first retrieved from the DLL and kernel will call functions onto it.

Another convenience is that the DLL does not need to be linked against any "kernel" library (the pure virtual interface does not need to be exported).

This normally works even across compilers (i.e. the executable compiled by a different compiler than the DLL, e.g. MSVC and GCC) - provided the virtual table implementation is the same. That is not mandated, but it is actually prerequisite for COM to work (compilers providing different implementation of polymorphism could not use Microsoft COM calls).

But especially in that case you absolutely must ensure that objects allocated in the DLL are not freed in the EXE and vice versa (they might use different heaps). If that is necessary, the interface should provide a pure virtual destroy() method, which ensures polymorphic calling of "delete this" in the correct memory context. But that might be an issue even with calling the functions directly (still in general should not free() memory malloc()-ed on the other side). Also C++ exceptions must not be allowed to pass the API boundary.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm exploring the answer.

Comment: One question, Does this technique (using .lib file) requires recompilation of components every time I make a change to the kernel?
By the way, is there any example of the dependency inversion technique?

Comment: I think I got the answer to the first part of the question. there is no need to recompile the programs that have used .lib files.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your design the other way round: that is, the 'kernel' is made a DLL and is loaded by your component application. Since it is the kernel that is providing services to the component, and not the other way round, this makes more sense.

Comment: The kernel is supposed to provide the infrastructure for components to communicate with each other through message-passing. I can't do that.