# GDB is not working if I have export symbols

Tags: c, windows, gdb, qemu, mingw-w64

So, I am working with QEMU, and I have a system of plugins for it, that are using bunch of symbols from the main executable. Everything is working fine in Linux, but porting plugins to windows caused many inconveniences (expectedly).

At first, i struggled with linking against executable. In Linux all you need is an option -rdynamic, that is not presented in windows. Eventually, I found a solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465275/whats-the-proper-way-to-link-against-an-executable-on-windows). So, I used --export-all-symbols linking option, and I was linking my plugins against an import library generated with -Wl,--out-implib. The result is a working qemu executable, and working plugins at the same time, all working as intended, except for gdb.

I am running gdb from MinGW64 shell like this: 
`$ gdb --args ./qemu-system-i386w testdisk.qcow2 -monitor stdio
(gdb) break tcg-plugin.c:164
Breakpoint 1 at 0x410f1c: file C:/fromgit/plugins_test/qemu-work/tcg/tcg-plugin.c, line 164.
(gdb) run`
But then i either get the following error:
 `Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x410f1c
Command aborted.`
Or it will start working, but none of breakpoints will be triggered, despite they definetely should.

I thought, that this may be caused by exporting all the symbols from qemu executable, so instead of using --export-all-symbols I qualified needed export symbols with __declspec(dllexport) attribute, but that didn't change anything. Furthermore, I discovered, that adding any export symbols at all to the executable will cause gdb to act faulty, the same way as described earlier.

It should be mentioned, that if I'm building just qemu, without any export symbols, I get an executable that works fine, and gdb is working fine with it.

So the question is - am I missing something? What can possibly cause gdb to not work?